# Unable to center item vertically with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center something horizontally and vertically using `flexbox` as described [Here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) ( *click "Both Horizontally and Vertically" => then click "Can you use flexbox?"*)

```css
.parent_test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sk-double-bounce {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}


.sk-double-bounce .sk-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20%;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-animation: sk-doubleBounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
            animation: sk-doubleBounce 2s infinite ease-in-out; }
  .sk-double-bounce .sk-double-bounce2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
            animation-delay: -1.0s; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-doubleBounce {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0); }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); } }

@keyframes sk-doubleBounce {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0); }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); } }
```

```html
  <h1><a href="https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#both-flexbox">centering-css-complete-guide/#both-flexbox</a>
  <div class="parent_test">
      <div class="sk-double-bounce">
        <div class="sk-child sk-double-bounce1"></div>
        <div class="sk-child sk-double-bounce2"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

But why isn't it centering vertically? [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zisawikohe/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify a `height` for parent, in order to make it vertically aligned.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.parent_test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh
}
.sk-double-bounce {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.sk-double-bounce .sk-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: sk-doubleBounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-doubleBounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.sk-double-bounce .sk-double-bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-doubleBounce {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes sk-doubleBounce {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_test">
  <div class="sk-double-bounce">
    <div class="sk-child sk-double-bounce1"></div>
    <div class="sk-child sk-double-bounce2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 100vh? That's something I never knew existed. Thanks! Let me know if there's a similar way without using the `parent_test` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the output, you'll see `.sk-double-bounce` is actually centered within `.parent_test`. The problem is that `.parent_test` has way lesser height. ( It only takes the amount of height required by it's content plus padding and border values).

You can now understand why the solution by @dippas works. If you want, you could remove the `.parent_test` wrapper, put flex rules in `body`, set `body`'s height to `100vh` and then put `.sk-double-bounce` div directly inside body. That would do the same job.